# Django - Extend User model on Two Difrent Models

Tags: django, forms, models, extend

I want to extend User Model in django with two different models. I mean, I want to have two registration panels for Vacancy and second one for Company. So I am going to have two different forms for User django class extended on attributes of Company. And User class extended on Vacancy class. How should I correlate this models to have my goal? Im open for new ideas. Thanks for any help Guys!

```
class Company(models.Model):
  name_company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  city = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  street = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  phone = models.CharField(max_length=9)
  email = models.EmailField(max_length=50)

class Vacancy(models.Model):
  fullname = models.CharField(max_length=100)
  age = models.IntegerField(blank=True, default=0)
  education = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, default='')
  origin = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True, default='')
  miasto = models.CharField(max_length=100, blank=True,default='')
  panstwo = models.CharField(max_length=100,blank=True,default='')
```

Comment: [Documentation](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/auth/customizing/#extending-the-existing-user-model) should help you out.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Add a foreign key to each table.

```
class Company(models.Model):
    user = models.ForeignKey(User, on_delete=models.CASCADE)
    name_company = models.CharField(max_length=100)
    ...
```

[Many to one docs are here](https://docs.djangoproject.com/en/2.0/topics/db/examples/many_to_one/)